# How to use .lg files in bot sdk

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

- I am making chat bot using bot sdk (.NET)
- I want to pass arguments to `template1` to be called using c#
- Making use of [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.languagegeneration?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)
- `var templates = Templates.ParseFile("a.lg");`
- `var result = templates.Evaluate("template1");`
- This function lies in .lg file `# template1(a, b) -${a + b}`
- For more details please consider this documentation [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/file-format/bot-builder-lg-file-format?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#cache-scope) documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by:

`var temp = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""a"": 2, ""b"": 3 }");`

`var result = templates.Evaluate("template1", temp);`

Comment: Hi @Aayush, Do you have any references for working sample code using .lg files? I am looking for a reference to construct multilingual bot without using translator API - so may be I can try .lg file per language and see if it helps